# Issue in Embark command 'embark ipfs'

Tags: embark

I am using Embark version 2.1 .I have used the command 'embark ipfs' but it returns the following error.

```
/usr/local/bin/ipfs
/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var  Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var  moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x) {process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var ret=

ReferenceError: build_dir is not defined
at IPFS.deploy (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/ipfs.js:16:37)
at Object.ipfs (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/index.js:265:10)
at Command.<anonymous> (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/cmd.js:136:17)
at Command.listener (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/node_modules/commander/index.js:301:8)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Command.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Command.parseArgs (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/node_modules/commander/index.js:615:12)
at Command.parse (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/node_modules/commander/index.js:458:21)
at Cmd.process (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/cmd.js:19:11)
at Object.process (/home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/index.js:31:9)
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in 2.2.0, please update to 2.2.0 and use the new command `embark upload ipfs`. you'll need to have a ipfs node running.

Comment: @ iurimatias I have tried to update but it generates the following error while using embark commands                                            /home/toshiba/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules/embark/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:37
    XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest; // jshint ignore: line
                   ^

ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Comment: That's an ongoing issue with web3.js which is affecting all tools & frameworks dependant on it: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/548 it should be fixed soon, once it does you can reinstall embark and it should work again

Comment: it's been fixed (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/0.18.2) please try again or try updating with ```npm install -g embark@2.2.1```

Comment: I have updated embark successfully.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is related to Embark and not Ethereum.

The source of the error is this [line](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework/blob/2.0.0/lib/ipfs.js#L16) from ipfs.js:

```
var cmd = ipfs_bin + " add -r " + build_dir;
```

Make sure you follow [Installation](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#installation) & [EmbarkJS](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#embarkjs)

The [documentation](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#deploying-to-ipfs) specifies:

> To deploy a dapp to IPFS, all you need to do is run a local IPFS node
>   and then run `embark ipfs`. If you want to deploy to the livenet then after configuring you account on `config/blockchain.json` on the `production` environment then you can deploy to that chain by specifying the environment `embark ipfs production`.

I assume you did not run a local node first.  To run a local IPFS node read [IPFS: Getting Started](https://ipfs.io/docs/getting-started/)

To run on livenet, configure `blockchain.json`, then run `embark ipfs production`